# Trying to find a way to create this minigame in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

So I've been going crazy for a few days trying to create this exercise in Flutter.

[image]

Namely, it is 'pop the lock' type minigame like the old arcade game. The red shape would go around in circle and function would fire when you click if it is inside the yellow circle and game would stop. I've been thinking about how to do it in Flutter, but I still can't seem to manage to do it. There is this library:

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_spinning_wheel

but I'm not sure how it would be useful. Anyone have any idea on how to do it, I don't really need the full code (though it would be useful), but just a general basic idea on how you'd do it. Thank you!

Comment: Seems like you need `CustomPaint`, `Stack` ,`Transform` and `AnimationController`

Answer (score 0):

It seems something you can accomplish using [percent_indicator](https://pub.dev/packages/percent_indicator) package.
It has lots of properties for you to work around.

[image]